# In Tensorflow, how can I select the minimum tensor among a few tensors?

Tags: python, tensorflow

According to the Tensorflow API, I know that I can reduce_min or reduce_max along a specific axis. I can also select the minimum tensor among two tensors as the following.

```
min = tf.minimum(x, y)
```

However, I want to know how I can select the minimum tensor among a group of tensors. If there is a function like min or max in tensor?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `stack` all the tensors and then use `reduce_min`

```
a = tf.constant([3])
b = tf.constant([2])
c = tf.constant([1])

with tf.Session() as sess:
   print(tf.reduce_min(tf.stack([a,b,c]),0).eval())
#[1]
```

Comment: Well, if there are only three variables, this is exactly the way to solve this problem. However, if I have 20 variables that I get from the output of the deep neural network. I think it is not easy to do that.

Comment: @Sean, I'm sure the outputs you've received must have been collated in some form. Mostly, it would be a list (say vars), in which case, you can easily stack the whole list specifying the respective axis. If its not a list, there must be a way to easily collate all of them into a list.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I collected the outputs in the form of the list.

Comment: Then use `tf.reduce_min(tf.stack(List),0)`